# Smartsheet API Set text in date column

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

Using the C# api, is there any way to set text into a DATE column using the api ?

I could not find any example or workaround to set string into a DATE column, and getting this error :

```
Date, did not conform to the strict requirements for type DATE.'
```

the column wasn't set to enforce date value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Strict property](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/smartsheet-csharp-sdk/html/P_Smartsheet_Api_Models_Cell_Strict.htm) on the `Cell` object, and set it to `false`. For example, your code might look like this

```
var cellToUpdate = new Cell
{
    ColumnId = 12345,
    Value = "text value",
    Strict = false

};
```